# Not able to run google sheet api from composer

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I'm running a google sheet extract python api from compute engine and its works fine
and I'm running the same from the composer, but its not working

In composer, I'm login to the vm with the same user and running ssh command and I'm using the same service account in google sheet & vm

The following is the error message I'm getting

```
 File "/home/utetwork_multiplier.py", line 15, in sheet_reade
    result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_name).execute(
  File "/hsite-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrappe
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs
  File "/on3.5/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 849, in execut
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/14r0cQ1RCXhLyd7i0VCrmddXOFiugFnfioRb6cYI_BWQ/values/Master%21A%3AJ?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes."

Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator.py", line 164, in execut
    .format(self.command, error_msg)
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: error running cmd: set -e;cd src/digital_platform && ../../venvs/bdp/bin/python -m.marketing.adnetwork_multiplier, error: Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_mai
    "__main__", mod_spec
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_cod
    exec(code, run_globals
  File "/home/tt/src/digital_platform//marketing/adnetwork_multiplier.py", line 74, in <module
    main(
  File "/home/tt/src/digital_platform//marketing/adnetwork_multiplier.py", line 28, in mai
    data = sheet_reader(range_name
  File "/home/tt/src/digital_platform//marketing/adnetwork_multiplier.py", line 15, in sheet_reade
    result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_name).execute(
  File "/home//venvs/bdp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrappe
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs
  File "/home//venvs/bdp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 849, in execut
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/14r0cQ1RCXhLydcYI_BWQ/values/Master%21A%3AJ?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes."


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred
```

Scopes

```
  scope = [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
    ]

    home = os.path.expanduser('~')
    csf = os.path.join(home, '.client_secret.json')
    token_filename = os.path.join(home, '.google_auth.dat')

    flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(csf, scope=scope, message="%s is missing" % csf)
    storage = Storage(token_filename)

    credentials = storage.get()
    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        flags = tools.argparser.parse_args(args=[])
        flags.noauth_local_webserver = True
        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags=flags)
```

Comment: Can you show how are you setting the Scopes to do the API calls?

Comment: updated above @Jescanellas

Comment: The scopes are enough to do a getValues request, but aren't they redundant? `auth/spreadsheets` already gives read permissions. Maybe you would prefer to set it only to `auth/spreadhseets.readonly`. Also, try removing the token file and giving permissions again.

Comment: Actually its running fine from local, but when I run the same command from composer its failing, that's something weird to me

Comment: Please edit your question and include enough code that we can test it nothing you have posted makes any requests against Google sheets.

Comment: Are you referring to [Cloud composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/overview)? If so, could you try adding the [cloud composer](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#composerv1) scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` ?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message you apear to be running [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)

That method requires one of the following scopes to access

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly

The error message states

> 403 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/14r0cQ1RCXhLydcYI_BWQ/values/Master%21A%3AJ?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

Which means that the user you have authenticated with was not authenticated with one of the required scopes above.   I suggest that you log out the user delete the credentials for that user and run your code again making sure that when it pops up the consent screen it is asking for one of the required scopes. I suspect you are running your script with outdated grants from the user.

Comment: the problem is I'm able to run it in machine directly - But when run the command from composer which using the same user is not working

Comment: ```t_coupon_usage_for_affiliates = SSHOperator(
    ssh_conn_id='bdp_vm',
    task_id='coupon_usage_for_affiliates',
    command=coupon_usage_for_affiliates,
    on_failure_callback=slack_failed_task,
    dag=dag) ```
i'm doing like above in composer

Comment: and it works fine when I use Jenkins to run the script

Comment: sounds like your not authorizing your code first.  Even if you run it on a machine it still needs to be authencated and if your using oauth2 that needs to have user intervention or saved refreshtoken that your code could load

Comment: I'm login with the same user

Comment: The user has to consent to it how is that going to happen on a server? unless you are logging in to that server and clicking ok to the consent in the browser window.